# CSS sprite problem, screwing up layout

Tags: css, sprite

I'm trying to update some code to use CSS sprites. In some situations it works fine, in others it screws up the page layout, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a fragment of the html ....

```
  <div id="footer"><!-- footer -->
  <div class="footer-top">
   <div class="footer-left">
    <div class="footer-right">
     <a href="/index.php" id="footer-logo"><img src="footer-logo.gif" /></a>

     <br /><br />
     <div>
<p>blah blah blah</p>

     <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

... and the CSS:

```
.footer-left {
        background: url(/images//footer-left_.gif) no-repeat left top;
}
```

I've created my sprite, and tried changing the CSS to:

```
.footer-left {

      background:url('/images/sprites.gif')  -66px -2px no-repeat;
      width:20px;
      height:99px;
}
```

The dimensions and offsets are correct, but the result isn't pretty. The sprite region shows in roughly the right place, but footer-logo.gif and the

text are messed up.

Any ideas please?

Comment: There's an unclosed `<div>` in your code. Could that be it? Sometimes the simplest things are the hardest to see.

Comment: Can you define "the result isn't pretty"?

Comment: Sorry, the missing </div> was my fault when copy/pasting.

Comment: Sorry, the missing </div> was my fault when copy/pasting. "the result isn't pretty" : I was having difficult finding the words. The contents of the footer-right div appear over to the left of where they should be (left of the footer-left image), and the paragraph of text squashes itself to the minimum width for one word. Actually, that's because I'm setting the width and height of the div isn't it - rather than just the image. How would I set the image dimensions without affecting the div dimensions?

Comment: @Harold Moberg, you can´t set the dimensions of a background image.

Comment: @Harold Moberg: You probably want to move `footer-right` outside `footer-left` instead of having it within it.

Answer (score 0):

The only things that have any effect on the logo and the text, are the dimensions you added; you set the `width` of the footer to `20px` and if that wasn´t there before, that definitely has an effect on your `bla bla bla` text and `.footer_right`.

Note that `.footer_right` and the text are both located inside your `20px` wide `footer_left`.

Are you sure your nested `div` structure is correct?